# How turn off Ubuntu Core login prompt tty

Tags: ubuntu-core

Is there a way to disable the login prompt after Ubuntu Core boot? The tty1 login prompt. I am running Ubuntu Frame.

The login appears after boot, the ubuntu frame renders a few seconds after the login prompt.